# Android sqlite retrieving row in onItemSelected

Tags: java, android, sqlite, spinner

I tried to retrieve the real `_id` of my table when clicked in a spinner this way:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String c = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
    long id_mark = parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Category: " + c + " | _id: " + id_mark, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

My table: (Some columns were erased by the user)

```
_id | category_name
---------------------
1   | NAME_HERE_1
3   | NAME_HERE_2
4   | NAME_HERE_3
7   | NAME_HERE_4
```

The Toast output is:

```
Category: NAME_HERE_2 | _id: 2
```

But the `id_mark` is different of `_id` of the my table. So how to proceed?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: without knowlage about your adapter class(type and how you feed it) it hard to say

Answer (score 0):

> But the `id_mark` is different of `_id` of the my table. So how to proceed?

If you're using a CursorAdapter and want `_id` from your table, simply use the forth parameter `id` in `onItemSelected()`. `id` already holds the table's primary key for the selected row.

Comment: But if the user erase the row 2, for example, the column  with _id=3 will pass to spinner with id=2. The result would be the same, no?

Comment: Not if you are using a Cursor and CursorAdapter. What type of Adapter are you using?

Comment: I used a ArrayAdapter to set in a spinner

Comment: Hmm, then you have to write a second query and store this information in a new Array then implement a way to bind your multiple Arrays and reflect any changes that might happen asynchronously is the database...  _Or_ you could switch to a CursorAdapter since it will be faster to write and faster to use than an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: I will try with a CursorAdapter first. Thanks a lot guy!